# Add custom shape ripple with selector on navigationview menu item

Tags: android, android-navigationview, material-components, material-components-android, navigationitem

I want to add a ripple effect with rounded corners rectangle with a selector for navigation view item. But it keeps adding the gray rectangle ripple effect.

navigation view

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar_menu"/>
```

drawer_item_bg.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_selected_item_bg"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ripple_navitem"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ripple_navitem"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_ripple_navitem"/>
```

custom_ripple_navitem.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="#360074FF">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Solution"

I started experimenting with ripple effect when I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55184220/4405457) question, and after some time I finished with this code.

**Note:** It is not real ripple effect, just a fake one. Let me know if you'll make an improved version of it.

*@layout/your_layout.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Widget_NavigationItem_NoRipple"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"/>
```

*@values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="Widget_NavigationItem_NoRipple">
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

*@drawable/drawer_item_background.xml*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_item_shape" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer_item_ripple" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

*@drawable/drawer_item_shape*

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/selectedItemBackgroundColor"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

*@drawable/drawer_item_ripple*

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the Material Components you can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
      app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.NavItem.Rounded"
      app:itemShapeFillColor="@color/selector_navitem"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.NavItem.Ripple"
      ../>
```

With the **`app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute you can define a custom shape for the each item:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.NavItem.Rounded" parent="">
      <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
      <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

With the **`app:itemShapeFillColor`** attribute you can define the color used to fill the shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.50" android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Finally use the **`android:theme`** to override the color used by the ripple.

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.NavItem.Ripple" parent="">
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires the version 1.1.0 of the Material Components library.